# (node-mariadb) knex makes query with wrapping table by single quotation (like --> select * from 'table')

Tags: sql, node.js, mariadb, knex.js

Knex makes query with wrapping table by single quotation!!

I'm using mariadb, node.js and i made a connection with knex module and connect-session-knex module.

When I run this code, (by node server.js)

```
knexMaria('users').where({userid:id}).asCallback(function(err, rows){ ... }
```

Error occurs(on that cmd)

```
Error: select * from 'users' where 'userid' = - You have an error in your 
Syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version
for right syntax to use near '' at line 1
      at Error (native)
```

So I tested my sql on my database.

I ran this code and same error occurred

```
select * from 'users' where userid=0;
```

What should I do for data I/O on mariaDB by knex?

My OS is Windows 7 - 32bit

Comment: When running the query directly against the database, don't use single quotes around `users`, instead use back ticks.  Not sure about `knex` though...

Comment: well.. thank you for your comment, but it was just test code to check what query makes same error(knex's error)